# CSS 100% height with absolute positioning top 0 bottom 0

Tags: html, css

I recently found a site that used a div with position absolute, and the top, left, right and bottom values all set to 0. This created a 100% high, 100% wide div. I am now using this as well, and was wondering if there is any reason not to?

It works really well, it's a simple solution, and the other way I was using had a bug I couldn't fix. The application I'm using this for should only every take up the browser window, and never needs to be bigger.

Comment: I think there are some issues with `position: absolute;` on mobile devices (certainly iPhone, from my own browsing experiences). But I'm not entirely sure if there's any real reason against it. So long as you deal with the `overflow`s properly.

Comment: Looks like Twitter Bootstrap is using the same technique in the Carousel as well setting top and bottom to 0 for the left and right carousel-controls.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> I am now using this as well, and was
>   wondering if there is any reason not
>   to?

This technique works fantastically in modern browsers - there is no reason not to use it.

*(unless you care about some really old browsers (IE5/6?), which [don't support](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/conflictingabsolutepositions/) setting `top` and `bottom` or `left` and `right` on the same element)*

[Here's an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069166/an-expanding-middle-in-css/5069468#5069468) I wrote earlier today which uses a similar technique.

Comment: Thanks, this application would fail epically in older browsers so no need to worry about that (It's a web based IDE running Ajax.org ACE as the primary editing component)

Comment: Is there any way to get this working in some form in older browsers (does it even work in FF<4?)

Comment: @Koorb: *Which* older browsers? It works in even IE7. I'm not certain, but I'd imagine it would work in even *Firefox 1*.

Comment: @thirtydot- just commented on your other answer- seems like Android browsers can't scroll the content with this technique.

Comment: Works fine for <div>, <a> and other elements. But not with <button>

Answer (score 5):

No, that's fine. Just make sure it doesn't glitch up on different browsers, depending on what you are doing. May I recommend making a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and testing it on [BrowserLab](https://browserlab.adobe.com/)?