# Div is not rendering according to screen size

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my app, I want everything to render according to screen size.

But a div is not rendering ;

Here is code :

```
<div id="tools" class="open">
.....
</div>
```

css :

```
#tools{
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 5%;
   overflow: hidden;
   background: #ffffff;
}
```

It doesn't render according to screen size. Please provide me some feasible solution for this

EDIT :

Some tools icon is used in above div. So whatever screen size is used, size of image icon remains same. it doesnt render according to screen size

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? What exactly happens?

Comment: Define "_render_" - do you mean it isn't the correct height? Is it showing at all?

Comment: Why you need `bottom: 0;` when you are using `top: 0;` and I guess what you are looking for is `width: 100%;`

Comment: It looks like you did not give it a height. If there is no content inside then it will not be visible. **Edit**: Mr. Alien is right, using `top` and `bottom` makes no sense. Although `width:5%` is fine if that's what he wants

Comment: The problem can't come from this div but from a parent div. Check if all its parent div don't have fixed values.

Comment: you need to give a height

Comment: it does work. just add a background color and `top:0;` `bottom:0;` makes a lot on sense

Comment: @unhandled-exceptionally `width:100%;` would make it the full size of the screen which is clearly not OP's intentions. it's obvious that his intentions is to create a "tools" sidebar

Answer (score 1):

If by "rendering" you understand that the `div` is not showing, that is because you need to specify its `height`. Furthermore, avoid using the ID for CSS identification. Use its class instead.

CSS:

```
.open {
    position:absolute; 
    top:0; 
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:5%;
    height:10%;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:#999999;
}
```

Instead of the `height:10%`, specify whatever height fits your needs.

[Working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/2cUBB/)

Comment: render means its width is not getting small and large according to screen size.

Comment: Actually you don't need to provide `height` at all

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#tools {
    position:absolute; 
    top:0; 
    right:0;
    width:5%;
    overflow:hidden; 
    background:red;
}

html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XvTVG/1/)

Comment: I cannot give width 100% because if i will give 100 % then it will cover whole area while at left of above div is a canvas.

Comment: 5% should work assuming that its parent (which might be `<body>`) has a specified width

Comment: @Rishi then give whatever width and height you want in percentage

Comment: But it doesn't work when screen size changes. It looks same for each screen size

Comment: @Rishi no, it DOES work. it's width is changing depending on screen size. increase width to 50% to see it clearly

Answer (score 0):

You have given "width:5%;". This might be a reason that your div is not showing a proper width according to the screen. Make it "width:100%".

Also, you have defined {position:absolute; top:0; right:0; bottom:0;}. If top is 0 then why have you given bottom as 0?? It is not required. You can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

> I think, the problem is not the size of the div you using. But the size of icon , which is not changing according to size of div. either you using very small image or given fix width to   them. 
>   try this with images . amke them with good standard size according to your app. and write this.

```
.class{max-width:100%}
```

> This with re-size them according to div size

Answer (score 0):

The problem can't come from this div because no fixed dimensions are defined. So the problem comes from a parent div. You have to check if all its parent div don't have fixed values.

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly fine just need to add some color so you can see it

http://jsfiddle.net/A2JjN/2/

```
background:red;
font-size:50px;
```

For anyone who is confused about why one might use `top:0; bottom:0;` then read this post [CSS 100% height with absolute positioning top 0 bottom 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070189/css-100-height-with-absolute-positioning-top-0-bottom-0)

Answer (score -1):

I got my solution. I just give width in pixels instead of % and it worked.

```
#tools{
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 50px;
   overflow: hidden;
   background: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Did you want tools to expand when the screen does? I thought that was the point in having used %