# Activate/deactivate events when moving the window

Tags: javascript, events, firefox, firefox-addon

Within my Firefox extension I'm trying to keep track when the window is actually the active window. For this, I add the following two listener to the window:

```
  window.addEventListener("deactivate", function(event) { alert("deactivate"); }, false);
  window.addEventListener("activate", function(event) { alert("activate");  }, false);
```

Basically everything works fine. When I toggle between different windows, or minimize/maximize Firefox, the events fire quite as I would expect it. However, both events also fired when I move the window even if it is already active. When I start moving the window, the "deactivate" event is fired; when I stop moving and release the mouse button, the "activate" event is fired. I have no idea how can I detect and ignore this behavior. Intuitively, the window is all the time active.

I tried to check before I handle the "deactivate" event if the mouse button is pressed. However, adding a "click" event listener to the window seem not to include the window's title bar. Anyone any idea how I can distinguish beween "really" de-/activating the window and moving the window? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Can you listen for the focus/blur window events instead? Not sure if you can do this for extensions, but in javascript the window focus event is thrown when a window is brought to the foreground (ie: activated) and the blur is thrown when another window is selected. Just an idea...

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I've already tried focus/blur. It seems to have the same effect, i.e. moving a focused window fires focus/blur event pair.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/504097/843033) to detect the browser position on the screen. If you do this at the start you can compare if they are changing.

Something like when the page loads:

```
var x,
    y,
    win = window;

if(win.screenTop !== undefined) {
    x = win.screenleft;
    y = win.screenTop;
} else {
    x = win.screenX;
    y = win.screenY
}
```

and compare those values to the current values when your events triggers.

(Note that this only works when the position of the window changes)