# How to position a div element at the center of the ACTUAL screen? (JQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, center

i need to position a div element at the center of the screen. I found a simple code below, but i need center of the ACTUAL screen, not "total height /2" of the page!

here is Jquery code that centers an element but not the actual screen;

```
jQuery.fn.center = function () {
this.css("position","absolute");
this.css("top", ( $(window).height() - this.height() ) / 2+$(window).scrollTop() + "px");
this.css("left", ( $(window).width() - this.width() ) / 2+$(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
return this;}
```

as i said, i need to calculate the actual screen sizes (like 1366*768 or whatever users resized their browsers) and position the element at the center of the screen. so, if i scroll down the page, always the centered div should be at the center, again.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504052/determining-position-of-the-browser-window-in-javascript) might get you going in the right direction. It's quite an old thread so I'm sure there's some nice library that wraps up the different calls required for the different browsers

Comment: @Matt There was a comment saying that IE now accepts screenX and screenY. So now its cross browser compatible. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're okay with using `fixed` positioning instead of `absolute`, you can use something like the following:

```js
jQuery.fn.center = function ()
{
    this.css("position","fixed");
    this.css("top", ($(window).height() / 2) - (this.outerHeight() / 2));
    this.css("left", ($(window).width() / 2) - (this.outerWidth() / 2));
    return this;
}

$('#myDiv').center();
$(window).resize(function(){
   $('#myDiv').center();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GoranMottram/D4BwA/1/

Answer (score 1):

it works..take this dive it as `#sample`

give its css style as

```
#sample{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:200px;//your wish
}
```

think it works..

Comment: If you read carefully, the question is about VERTICAL centering, and you're proposing HORIZONTAL centering.

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS:

```
var width=$("#div").css("width");
var half=width/2;
$("#div").css("marginLeft","-"+half+"px");
```

Change #div with your selector.

Comment: Again... If you read carefully, the question is about VERTICAL centering, and you're proposing HORIZONTAL centering.