# Listener for Direction of Resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, viewport, onresize

I have a right pointing triangle.

▶

On resize, the triangle should move in the direction of the resize, and when it changes direction, the triangle should flip horizontally, without ever going out of the screen.

Is there a way to listen to the direction (LEFT / RIGHT) in which the browser is being resized?

Comment: You can tell which way the window is changing (getting bigger or smaller), but not which edge of the screen the user used to resize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504052/determining-position-of-the-browser-window-in-javascript). You can get the browser window position and subtract the last position (saved from the previous resize call). If the result is non-zero in **x** you can assume the left edge was used, same goes for **y** and the top edge.

Here is a quick example of this :

```
    var last_pos_x = window.screenX;
    var last_pos_y = window.screenY;

    window.addEventListener('resize', function() {

        var diff_x =  window.screenX - last_pos_x;
        var diff_y =  window.screenY - last_pos_y;

        last_pos_x = window.screenX;
        last_pos_y = window.screenY;

        console.log(diff_x, diff_y)
    });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: problem with this is, is if the user moves the browser, u get corrupted data @GRoy